# Karma/Jasmine/PhantomJS "TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function"

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

while unit testing I get the exception:

> TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function

I already imported BrowserModule, HttpClient and HttpHandler to my *.spec.ts and to my *.module.ts -files.

You got a idea what the error coursed?